# What is the best PHP function to get a file hidden in the backend?

Tags: php, file, security

I have files in different formats: ePub/mobi/pdf/etc.

But I don't want anyone to access those files and certain files cannot be access by some users. So I cannot use HTTP to protect the folder that contains the files because it might give access to one user to all the files...

So is there a PHP function that can get a file from a folder that cannot be access publicly to then send it back to the user?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want to look at sending file downloads with PHP. You can store your files outside of your web-accessible folder, and use `readfile()` in a PHP script to send the file as a download when a user clicks a purchase link or whatever.

Comment: Add an .htaccess to your folders to prevent direct access through browsers. Then work with file_get_contents or readfile.

Comment: By far the best way I've seen is storing outside the document root & using [mod-xsendfile](https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/) to hand over the actual delivery to the webserver so your PHP script won't have to deal with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just store the file out of the root directory that holds all of your front-facing files. So assuming your directory structure is as such:

```
root
-- public_html
-- -- access_book.php
-- -- index.php
-- -- ...
-- books
-- -- mobi_dick.pdf
-- -- ...
```

Then, just grab your file with a relative path (here is an example pulled from [`readfile`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php)):

```
<?php
    // Replace this with the path to the actual file
    $file = '../books/mobi_dick.pdf';

    if (file_exists($file)) {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));

        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile($file);
        exit;
    }
?>
```

You may have to configure [`open_basedir`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) for PHP to open a file outside of the web root.

Comment: But wait... How do I make the user download it after I call file_get_contents?

Comment: @Jean-NicolasBoulayDesjardins I have expanded my answer with a example. Of course, you should consider caching the file (instead of requiring the client to redownload the file each time).

Comment: I tried with a PDF file and I just get a blank page. At least it does not send me a Error message like the other answer.

Comment: I tried changing the Content-Type to application/pdf... No change. Just a blank page.

Comment: @Jean-NicolasBoulayDesjardins can you show me what error message you're seeing? You may have to change your error reporting level to `E_ALL`.

Comment: I am not getting any errors from your code. I am just getting a blank page. But even adding: error_reporting(E_ALL); does not show anything. Also I don't have access to any server logs. I am using a share host.

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting. What happens when you comment out the `exit` and add some HTML after the PHP tag?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Look at [fpassthru()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fpassthru.php) and use it like this:

```php
$mime_type = 'image/jpg'; // or whatever
$file_name = '/private/some.jpg'; // or whatever
// TODO: add check for If-Modified-Since or ETag HTTP header and handle appropriately
if (($fp = fopen($file_name, 'r')) === false)
{
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
    exit(0);
}
header('Content-Type: ' . $mime_type);
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file_name));
fpassthru($fp);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: For some reason it is not working. When I try it on Google Chrome I get this error: 404 Not Found. The Strange thing is when I do an echo before your code I get the message but nothing else... It also does not work in Safari.

Comment: Check the permissions on the file to make sure is accessible to the user your web server is running as.  You can use is_readable() to check if this is the issue:

if (!is_readable($file_name)) {
   header("HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error");
   exit(0);
}